# Is it possible to still use Laravel 5 Accessors to access multiple attributes

Tags: php, model, accessor, laravel-5

Perhaps I'm missing something very obvious here but if I do:

```
public function getName()
{
    return $this->first_name . ' ' . $this->last_name;
}
```

and then in my view do

```
$user->name
```

I get nothing back. But if I run

```
$user->getName()
```

Then it works as expected. Is it not possible to create an accessor that accesses multiple attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use something like this in your `User` model as an `accesor`:

```
public function getNameAttribute($value)
{
    return $this->first_name . ' ' . $this->last_name;
}
```

So you can use `$user->name` property. The name format is `getPropertyAttribute`.

Comment: Ahh, I assumed I was stuck using the $value being passed in from the attribute and couldn't see a $value being present if I called the method getNameAttribute.

Answer (score 3):

Your function should should have name `getNameAttribute` and not `getName` to make it work as accessor ([docs reference](http://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators)) and use `$user->name` to access result of your accessor. Now you created standard function and if you want to run it you need to run function as in all standard PHP functions.